# Disable record if someone else has opened same record in vuejs

Tags: sockets, vue.js

I am working on an vuejs based application with Laravel. I need to disable or disallow users to open a record if same record has been opened already.

I have done with some RnD and got few suggestions:

- Using some status field in database end and check on every request to open that if not engaged then open otherwise show message that opened by someone else
- Maybe can be done by socket in which maintain the record id along the socket port and keep checking on events

Please guide that which one can be best and also share if other than this can be a possibility.

Comment: Your are on the right track. If you by any chance using postgresql then you could call pg_notify in trigger to pass json message to node.js and node.js would pass it to all connected clients via web socket. If you are out of luck and use database without similar "push" interface then you could broadcast record "locks" manually from php API endpoint, i.e. php->node->clients. Also be ready to use memcached for session management to share session between php and node to provide auth checks at node side.

Comment: ah great, yes we are using `postgresql` ok let me do RnD on it.

Comment: I implemented such thing recently so I could write an answer with ready-to-use code snippets quite easily. I'm sure that need for such solution pops up from time to time so people could find such answer quite useful. You can try to implement it yourself and share solution with us. Let me know if you encounter any difficulties or would you like me to provide you with spoiler solution :-)

Comment: Thanks @MaximSagaydachny I will try to implement on Monday and then I will discuss with you.